# How to perform action on event in Basic jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bjqs

I got the slider using bjqs plugin from http://www.basic-slider.com/
going through the documentation I found only options, but no events/functions.
what I mean by events/functions is something like onSlideChange, onSlideDisplay

I found other plugins providing something like that ( bxslider has onSlideBefore, onSlideAfter ..etc) but I can't change the used plugin since it's legacy code not mine to start all over

any pointers to such implementation or even how to implement this functionality is mostly appreciated

thank you

**update**
I've tried fiddling with this in [[here]](http://jsfiddle.net/eng_katia/44c6sgdo/) (please ignore the ugly style ^_^)

```
 if (i == (length - 1)) {
        isLastSlide = "isLastSlide=\"true\"";
    }
    $(".bjqs").append("<li " + isLastSlide 
+ "><img src='http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png' title='slide number " 
+ (i + 1) + "'></li>");

}
```

added a flag to the desired slide (test case: last slide)

```
$('li[isLastSlide="TRUE"]:visible').css('background', 'red');
```

then tried to detect when the slide having that flag is being displayed to perform something like changing style or even calling a function but it's not working yet

I'll keep trying and updating

1- successfully changed css for the desired slide.
I just had an error in comparing the flag value

```
$('li[isLastSlide="true"]:visible').css('background', 'red');
```

now working on calling a function
[image]

Comment: Generally if a plugin does not have features (like events), you either need to re-write the plugin or choose a better plugin (that has those features/events). With cheap/free plugins you often get what you pay for :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie re-write, as in writing it all from scratch? can't I just build on top of it? I'm trying to extend the plugin right now

Comment: If they provide commented source code, you can modify it. If you understand the structure you may be able to extend it from the outside.

Comment: https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/blob/master/js/bjqs-1.3.js#L617 raise your events in `go` function

Comment: @aleha seems promising, but care to explain more? thanks anyway

Comment: @katia it's hard to do in two words. At line https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/blob/master/js/bjqs-1.3.js#L51 define new parameter - empty function. Call it in `go` function. When initialize your plugin give to him your function as specified parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of aleha's comment and link I was able to extend the plugin to pass in a function

here's the code to help whoever meets this issue

```
(function($) {

"use strict";

$.fn.bjqs = function(o) {

    // slider default settings
    var defaults = {
        // w + h to enforce consistency
        width: 700,
        height: 300,
        // transition valuess
        animtype: 'fade',
        animduration: 450, // length of transition
        animspeed: 4000, // delay between transitions
        automatic: true, // enable/disable automatic slide rotation

        // control and marker configuration
        showcontrols: true, // enable/disable next + previous UI elements
        centercontrols: true, // vertically center controls
        nexttext: 'Next', // text/html inside next UI element
        prevtext: 'Prev', // text/html inside previous UI element
        showmarkers: true, // enable/disable individual slide UI markers
        centermarkers: true, // horizontally center markers

        // interaction values
        keyboardnav: true, // enable/disable keyboard navigation
        hoverpause: true, // enable/disable pause slides on hover

        // presentational options
        usecaptions: true, // enable/disable captions using img title attribute
        randomstart: false, // start from a random slide
        responsive: false     // enable responsive behaviour

        //custom callback
        ,custom: null
    };

    // create settings from defauls and user options
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, o);

    // slider elements
    var $wrapper = this,
            $slider = $wrapper.find('ul.bjqs'),
            $slides = $slider.children('li'),
            // control elements
            $c_wrapper = null,
            $c_fwd = null,
            $c_prev = null,
            // marker elements
            $m_wrapper = null,
            $m_markers = null,
            // elements for slide animation
            $canvas = null,
            $clone_first = null,
            $clone_last = null;

    // state management object
    var state = {
        slidecount: $slides.length, // total number of slides
        animating: false, // bool: is transition is progress
        paused: false, // bool: is the slider paused
        currentslide: 1, // current slide being viewed (not 0 based)
        nextslide: 0, // slide to view next (not 0 based)
        currentindex: 0, // current slide being viewed (0 based)
        nextindex: 0, // slide to view next (0 based)
        interval: null              // interval for automatic rotation
    };

    var responsive = {
        width: null,
        height: null,
        ratio: null
    };

    // helpful variables
    var vars = {
        fwd: 'forward',
        prev: 'previous'
    };

    // run through options and initialise settings
    var init = function() {

        // differentiate slider li from content li
        $slides.addClass('bjqs-slide');

        // conf dimensions, responsive or static
        if (settings.responsive) {
            conf_responsive();
        }
        else {
            conf_static();
        }

        // configurations only avaliable if more than 1 slide
        if (state.slidecount > 1) {

            // enable random start
            if (settings.randomstart) {
                conf_random();
            }

            // create and show controls
            if (settings.showcontrols) {
                conf_controls();
            }

            // create and show markers
            if (settings.showmarkers) {
                conf_markers();
            }

            // enable slidenumboard navigation
            if (settings.keyboardnav) {
                conf_keynav();
            }

            // enable pause on hover
            if (settings.hoverpause && settings.automatic) {
                conf_hoverpause();
            }

            // conf slide animation
            if (settings.animtype === 'slide') {
                conf_slide();
            }

        } else {
            // Stop automatic animation, because we only have one slide! 
            settings.automatic = false;
        }

        if (settings.usecaptions) {
            conf_captions();
        }

        // TODO: need to accomodate random start for slide transition setting
        if (settings.animtype === 'slide' && !settings.randomstart) {
            state.currentindex = 1;
            state.currentslide = 2;
        }

        // slide components are hidden by default, show them now
        $slider.show();
        $slides.eq(state.currentindex).show();

        // Finally, if automatic is set to true, kick off the interval
        if (settings.automatic) {
            state.interval = setInterval(function() {
                go(vars.fwd, false, settings.custom);
            }, settings.animspeed);
        }

    };

    var conf_responsive = function() {

        responsive.width = $wrapper.outerWidth();
        responsive.ratio = responsive.width / settings.width,
                responsive.height = settings.height * responsive.ratio;

        if (settings.animtype === 'fade') {

            // initial setup
            $slides.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': '100%'
            });
            $slides.children('img').css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': '100%'
            });
            $slider.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': '100%'
            });
            $wrapper.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'max-width': settings.width,
                'position': 'relative'
            });

            if (responsive.width < settings.width) {

                $slides.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slides.children('img').css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slider.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $wrapper.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });

            }

            $(window).resize(function() {

                // calculate and update dimensions
                responsive.width = $wrapper.outerWidth();
                responsive.ratio = responsive.width / settings.width,
                        responsive.height = settings.height * responsive.ratio;

                $slides.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slides.children('img').css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slider.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $wrapper.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });

            });

        }

        if (settings.animtype === 'slide') {

            // initial setup
            $slides.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': settings.width
            });
            $slides.children('img').css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': settings.width
            });
            $slider.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'width': settings.width * settings.slidecount
            });
            $wrapper.css({
                'height': settings.height,
                'max-width': settings.width,
                'position': 'relative'
            });

            if (responsive.width < settings.width) {

                $slides.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slides.children('img').css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $slider.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $wrapper.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });

            }

            $(window).resize(function() {

                // calculate and update dimensions
                responsive.width = $wrapper.outerWidth(),
                        responsive.ratio = responsive.width / settings.width,
                        responsive.height = settings.height * responsive.ratio;

                $slides.css({
                    'height': responsive.height,
                    'width': responsive.width
                });
                $slides.children('img').css({
                    'height': responsive.height,
                    'width': responsive.width
                });
                $slider.css({
                    'height': responsive.height,
                    'width': responsive.width * settings.slidecount
                });
                $wrapper.css({
                    'height': responsive.height
                });
                $canvas.css({
                    'height': responsive.height,
                    'width': responsive.width
                });

                resize_complete(function() {
                    go(false, state.currentslide, settings.custom);
                }, 200, "some unique string");

            });

        }

    };

    var resize_complete = (function() {

        var timers = {};

        return function(callback, ms, uniqueId) {
            if (!uniqueId) {
                uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
            }
            if (timers[uniqueId]) {
                clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
            }
            timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };

    })();

    // enforce fixed sizing on slides, slider and wrapper
    var conf_static = function() {

        $slides.css({
            'height': settings.height,
            'width': settings.width
        });
        $slider.css({
            'height': settings.height,
            'width': settings.width
        });
        $wrapper.css({
            'height': settings.height,
            'width': settings.width,
            'position': 'relative'
        });

    };

    var conf_slide = function() {

        // create two extra elements which are clones of the first and last slides
        $clone_first = $slides.eq(0).clone();
        $clone_last = $slides.eq(state.slidecount - 1).clone();

        // add them to the DOM where we need them
        $clone_first.attr({'data-clone': 'last', 'data-slide': 0}).appendTo($slider).show();
        $clone_last.attr({'data-clone': 'first', 'data-slide': 0}).prependTo($slider).show();

        // update the elements object
        $slides = $slider.children('li');
        state.slidecount = $slides.length;

        // create a 'canvas' element which is neccessary for the slide animation to work
        $canvas = $('<div class="bjqs-wrapper"></div>');

        // if the slider is responsive && the calculated width is less than the max width
        if (settings.responsive && (responsive.width < settings.width)) {

            $canvas.css({
                'width': responsive.width,
                'height': responsive.height,
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'position': 'relative'
            });

            // update the dimensions to the slider to accomodate all the slides side by side
            $slider.css({
                'width': responsive.width * (state.slidecount + 2),
                'left': -responsive.width * state.currentslide
            });

        }
        else {

            $canvas.css({
                'width': settings.width,
                'height': settings.height,
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'position': 'relative'
            });

            // update the dimensions to the slider to accomodate all the slides side by side
            $slider.css({
                'width': settings.width * (state.slidecount + 2),
                'left': -settings.width * state.currentslide
            });

        }

        // add some inline styles which will align our slides for left-right sliding
        $slides.css({
            'float': 'left',
            'position': 'relative',
            'display': 'list-item'
        });

        // 'everything.. in it's right place'
        $canvas.prependTo($wrapper);
        $slider.appendTo($canvas);

    };

    var conf_controls = function() {

        // create the elements for the controls
        $c_wrapper = $('<ul class="bjqs-controls"></ul>');
        $c_fwd = $('<li class="bjqs-next"><a href="#" data-direction="' + vars.fwd + '">' + settings.nexttext + '</a></li>');
        $c_prev = $('<li class="bjqs-prev"><a href="#" data-direction="' + vars.prev + '">' + settings.prevtext + '</a></li>');

        // bind click events
        $c_wrapper.on('click', 'a', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction');

            if (!state.animating) {

                if (direction === vars.fwd) {
                    go(vars.fwd, false, settings.custom);
                }

                if (direction === vars.prev) {
                    go(vars.prev, false, settings.custom);
                }

            }

        });

        // put 'em all together
        $c_prev.appendTo($c_wrapper);
        $c_fwd.appendTo($c_wrapper);
        $c_wrapper.appendTo($wrapper);

        // vertically center the controls
        if (settings.centercontrols) {

            $c_wrapper.addClass('v-centered');

            // calculate offset % for vertical positioning
            var offset_px = ($wrapper.height() - $c_fwd.children('a').outerHeight()) / 2,
                    ratio = (offset_px / settings.height) * 100,
                    offset = ratio + '%';

            $c_fwd.find('a').css('top', offset);
            $c_prev.find('a').css('top', offset);

        }

    };

    var conf_markers = function() {

        // create a wrapper for our markers
        $m_wrapper = $('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>');

        // for every slide, create a marker
        $.each($slides, function(key, slide) {

            var slidenum = key + 1,
                    gotoslide = key + 1;

            if (settings.animtype === 'slide') {
                // + 2 to account for clones
                gotoslide = key + 2;
            }

            var marker = $('<li><a href="#">' + slidenum + '</a></li>');

            // set the first marker to be active
            if (slidenum === state.currentslide) {
                marker.addClass('active-marker');
            }

            // bind the click event
            marker.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!state.animating && state.currentslide !== gotoslide) {
                    go(false, gotoslide, settings.custom);
                }
            });

            // add the marker to the wrapper
            marker.appendTo($m_wrapper);

        });

        $m_wrapper.appendTo($wrapper);
        $m_markers = $m_wrapper.find('li');

        // center the markers
        if (settings.centermarkers) {
            $m_wrapper.addClass('h-centered');
            var offset = (settings.width - $m_wrapper.width()) / 2;
            $m_wrapper.css('left', offset);
        }

    };

    var conf_keynav = function() {

        $(document).keyup(function(event) {

            if (!state.paused) {
                clearInterval(state.interval);
                state.paused = true;
            }

            if (!state.animating) {
                if (event.keyCode === 39) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    go(vars.fwd, false, settings.custom);
                } else if (event.keyCode === 37) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    go(vars.prev, false, settings.custom);
                }
            }

            if (state.paused && settings.automatic) {
                state.interval = setInterval(function() {
                    go(vars.fwd);
                }, settings.animspeed);
                state.paused = false;
            }

        });

    };

    var conf_hoverpause = function() {

        $wrapper.hover(function() {
            if (!state.paused) {
                clearInterval(state.interval);
                state.paused = true;
            }
        }, function() {
            if (state.paused) {
                state.interval = setInterval(function() {
                    go(vars.fwd, false, settings.custom);
                }, settings.animspeed);
                state.paused = false;
            }
        });

    };

    var conf_captions = function() {

        $.each($slides, function(key, slide) {

            var caption = $(slide).children('img:first-child').attr('title');

            // Account for images wrapped in links
            if (!caption) {
                caption = $(slide).children('a').find('img:first-child').attr('title');
            }

            if (caption) {
                caption = $('<p class="bjqs-caption">' + caption + '</p>');
                caption.appendTo($(slide));
            }

        });

    };

    var conf_random = function() {

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * state.slidecount) + 1;
        state.currentslide = rand;
        state.currentindex = rand - 1;

    };

    var set_next = function(direction) {

        if (direction === vars.fwd) {

            if ($slides.eq(state.currentindex).next().length) {
                state.nextindex = state.currentindex + 1;
                state.nextslide = state.currentslide + 1;
            }
            else {
                state.nextindex = 0;
                state.nextslide = 1;
            }

        }
        else {

            if ($slides.eq(state.currentindex).prev().length) {
                state.nextindex = state.currentindex - 1;
                state.nextslide = state.currentslide - 1;
            }
            else {
                state.nextindex = state.slidecount - 1;
                state.nextslide = state.slidecount;
            }

        }

    };

    var go = function(direction, position, custom) {

        // only if we're not already doing things
        if (!state.animating) {

            // doing things
            state.animating = true;

            if (position) {
                state.nextslide = position;
                state.nextindex = position - 1;
            }
            else {
                set_next(direction);
            }

            // fade animation
            if (settings.animtype === 'fade') {

                if (settings.showmarkers) {
                    $m_markers.removeClass('active-marker');
                    $m_markers.eq(state.nextindex).addClass('active-marker');
                }

                // fade out current
                $slides.eq(state.currentindex).fadeOut(settings.animduration);
                // fade in next
                $slides.eq(state.nextindex).fadeIn(settings.animduration, function() {

                    // update state variables
                    state.animating = false;
                    state.currentslide = state.nextslide;
                    state.currentindex = state.nextindex;

                });

            }

            // slide animation
            if (settings.animtype === 'slide') {

                if (settings.showmarkers) {

                    var markerindex = state.nextindex - 1;

                    if (markerindex === state.slidecount - 2) {
                        markerindex = 0;
                    }
                    else if (markerindex === -1) {
                        markerindex = state.slidecount - 3;
                    }

                    $m_markers.removeClass('active-marker');
                    $m_markers.eq(markerindex).addClass('active-marker');
                }

                // if the slider is responsive && the calculated width is less than the max width
                if (settings.responsive && (responsive.width < settings.width)) {
                    state.slidewidth = responsive.width;
                }
                else {
                    state.slidewidth = settings.width;
                }

                $slider.animate({'left': -state.nextindex * state.slidewidth}, settings.animduration, function() {

                    state.currentslide = state.nextslide;
                    state.currentindex = state.nextindex;

                    // is the current slide a clone?
                    if ($slides.eq(state.currentindex).attr('data-clone') === 'last') {

                        // affirmative, at the last slide (clone of first)
                        $slider.css({'left': -state.slidewidth});
                        state.currentslide = 2;
                        state.currentindex = 1;

                    }
                    else if ($slides.eq(state.currentindex).attr('data-clone') === 'first') {

                        // affirmative, at the fist slide (clone of last)
                        $slider.css({'left': -state.slidewidth * (state.slidecount - 2)});
                        state.currentslide = state.slidecount - 1;
                        state.currentindex = state.slidecount - 2;

                    }

                    state.animating = false;

                });

            }

        }
        if (typeof custom !== "undefined" || custom === null) {
            if (typeof custom == "function") {
                custom();
            }
        }
    };

    // lets get the party started :)
    init();

};

})(jQuery);
```